# SQL Selecting the minimum value after a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner to SQL so this is quite possibly a very simple question.  I have a table with postage service information like so:

```
ID Service              Max_Weight Cost
----------------------------------------
1  SecondClassStandard  0.10       0.95

2  SecondClassStandard  0.25       1.19

3  SecondClassStandard  0.50       1.51

4  SecondClassStandard  0.75       2.05

5  SecondClassStandard  1.00       2.80
```

How can I perform the following query (as an example):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' AND Max_Weight >= 0.075;`

and from the result, get one service that will satisfy the weight requirement.  In other words, select the one result that is suitable - for example, from the query above, it should only return:

```
1|SecondClassStandard|0.10|0.95
```

However, if I was to do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' AND Max_Weight >= 0.105;`

It should return:

```
2|SecondClassStandard|0.25|1.19
```

Comment: whats the problem here, query is alright

Comment: I only want the query to return a single result based on the max_weight.  If i were to run the above queries, it would select all the rows except the ones the weight is under.

Comment: Do you only want ID 2? Why not ID 3, 4, or 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`LIMIT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) clause like

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' 
AND Max_Weight >= 0.075 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIMIT` to just get the first row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' AND Max_Weight >= 0.075 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' AND Max_Weight >= 0.105 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE Service = 'SecondClassStandard' 
AND Max_Weight >= 0.075 
ORDER BY Max_Weight ASC Limit 1;
```